# Following up on Italian citizenship

Tags: citizenship, australia, australian-citizens, italian-citizens

I applied for Italian citizenship early this year (around January). I was eligible to do so because of my Italian heritage.

According to [this](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.conssydney.esteri.it/consolato_sydney/resource/doc/2016/03/how_to_-_italian_citizenship_by_descent.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwipgNub4LTWAhWGp5QKHU3qB4sQFgh_MA4&usg=AFQjCNHaVPGft27uRCuTb6jUEeLLm1ZIOQ) document provided by the embassy, I should expect a waiting period of 2-8 weeks. It is now September. I contacted the embassy in May to enquire about the status of my application; they informed me that my application is still being processed, and that they will contact me when they have more information. How should I proceed?

Comment: Do you know which municipality is processing your application?

Comment: @phoog I do not.